# Where to place repetitive business logic in Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have repetitive business logic used by many services in node.js, can put those logics in utils folder? And if yes can I manipulate database in util file?

Comment: Usually the best rule is - **move files around until it feels right**

Comment: I define sharable tasks into modules or services separated into their owned directories. Utils are usually used for small or helper functions like date-time manipulating, converting data, etc.